# Using Android AccessibilityService.getWindows() to get a list of View elements on screen

Tags: android, window, android-view, accessibilityservice

Is it possible to use AccessibilityService.getWindows() to get a list of View elements that are currently displayed on screen, including their Z-level, which one is the top-most element, and the package names that they belong to? If so, how?

I'm not trying to build a full blown AccessibilityService, I'm only interested in the getWindows() method to get a list of windows on screen. I tried the following code:

```
AccessibilityService myService = new AccessibilityService() {
  @Override
  public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onInterrupt() {

  }
};
List<AccessibilityWindowInfo> windowList = myService.getWindows();
if (windowList.isEmpty()) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Window list is empty");
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Window list is not empty");
}
```

However, the window list is always empty. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find any documentation/example on using `getWindows()`.

Comment: In order to behave optimally in accordance to screen content, can accessibilityservice applications access the raw display pixel-map as well as get notified of notification pop-ups?

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate an accessibility service this way.  Accessibility services get intimate access to view information.  Allowing them to be started willy nilly from Activities and other classes would be a very severe security risk.  You have to register your accessibility service with the system and start it from the accessibility services settings menu. To do this you should have an entry in your manifest file that looks something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <service
        android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_config" />

    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MyServiceSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.accessibilityservice.SERVICE_SETTINGS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Along with a raw xml file called "service_config" that contains stuff like this:

```
<accessibility-service 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:settingsActivity="com.yourpackage.MyServiceSettingsActivity"
/>
```

You then start your service from the same area that TalkBack is started, by turnning the switch on for your service.